# python find all strings starting and ending with certain characters

Tags: python, string, findall

How can I extract with python all strings starting with `'a['` and ending with `']'`?

for example

```
str= "a[0]*x**3+a[13]"

result : a[0], a[13]
```

thanks

Comment: use regex will help you solve this

Answer (score 0):

We can use `re.findall` here:

```py
inp = "a[0]*x**3+a[13]"
matches = re.findall(r'\ba\[.*?\]', inp)
print(matches)  # ['a[0]', 'a[13]']
```